# CSS Nested Position

Tags: html, css

I have multiple divs on my website. Divs are usually `position: absolute;`. It contains. My problem is that when I enlarge and shrink the page, they get inside or they are not where I want them. I want them to stay where it all is. Can I solve this problem with a border or how i solve this problem?

Below is a sample code that looks like a problem:

```css
.a1{
   position: absolute;
   top: 25%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
   width: 27px;
   height: 27px;
   border-radius:50%;
   border: 5px solid #ddd;
 }
 
.a2{
   position: absolute;
   top: 45%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
   width: 27px;
   height: 27px;
   border-radius:50%;
   border: 5px solid #ddd;
 }
 
.a3{
   position: absolute;
   top: 65%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
   width: 27px;
   height: 27px;
   border-radius:50%;
   border: 5px solid #ddd;
 }
```

```html
<div class="a1"></div>
<div class="a2"></div>
<div class="a3"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use percentage values only where they don't interfere with the size of element. So in your case, you could use pixel values for the vertical positions, or you use "calc" values which have the percentage of the central element plus/minus  a fixed pixel value:

```css
.a1{
   position: absolute;
   top: calc(45% - 60px);
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
   width: 27px;
   height: 27px;
   border-radius:50%;
   border: 5px solid #ddd;
 }
 
.a2{
   position: absolute;
   top: 45%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
   width: 27px;
   height: 27px;
   border-radius:50%;
   border: 5px solid #ddd;
 }
 
.a3{
   position: absolute;
   top: calc(45% + 60px);
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
   width: 27px;
   height: 27px;
   border-radius:50%;
   border: 5px solid #ddd;
 }
```

```html
<div class="a1"></div>
<div class="a2"></div>
<div class="a3"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I wonder if the correct proportional dimensions can change when the page size changes? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add a div wrapping the others, position this one wherever you want, and make the inside divs have a relative position:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="a1"></div>
    <div class="a2"></div>
    <div class="a3"></div>
</div>
```

`.a1, .a2, .a3 {position: relative}`

This way you have more and better control.